# How to retrieve any group objects where any of the users in the group has a certain email

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to retrieve any group objects where any of the users in the group has a certain email.

I have one proposed way which is super manual ugly (retrieve all profiles and then their groups and then retrieve the objects - very backward).

As described above

Do you have a more elegant way in one query?

```
Group
>Team
>Users
>Profile
>Email
- gmail.com
- yahoo.com
- test.com
```

Comment: Show us your schema  please

Comment: sorry for late reply, actually i founded solution to that problem myself.